# How to fork/clone a process in Erlang

Tags: process, erlang, fork

How to fork/clone a process in Erlang, as the `fork` in Unix?

I have searched a lot but just got nothing.

Maybe the usage looks like this:

```
case fork() of
  {parent, Pid} ->
    in_parent_process_now();
  {child, Pid} ->
    in_child_process_now();
  {error, Msg} ->
    report_fork_error(Msg)
end.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

In order to explain my point better, take the following C code as an example:

```
f();
fork();
g();
```

Here the return value of `fork()` is ignored, so the next steps of both the parent process and the child process are the same, which is to execute `g()`.

Can I achieve this in Erlang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, there is generic pattern to implement processes in erlang:

```
loop( State ) ->
   receive
      Message ->
         NewState = process( Message, State ),
         loop( NewState )
   end.
```

In each quant of time process has a `State`. So if you want to "fork" some process from current - you have to pass specific message for it. Process have to recognize that message and spawn the new process with copy of its current state in spawned process.

I've created example, to illustrate text above:

```
-module( test ).
-export( [ fork/1, get_state/1, change_state/2 ] ).
-export( [ loop/1 ] ).

loop( State ) ->
        receive
                { fork, Sender } ->
                        %%
                        %% if you want to link with child process
                        %% call spawn_link instead of spawn
                        %%
                        ClonePid = spawn( ?MODULE, loop, [ State ] ),
                        responseTo( Sender, ClonePid ),
                        loop( State );

                { get_state, Sender } ->
                        responseTo( Sender, { curr_state, State } ),
                        loop( State );

                { change_state, Data, Sender } ->
                        { Response, NewState } = processData( Data, State ),
                        responseTo( Sender, Response ),
                        loop( NewState )
        end.

fork( Pid ) ->
        Ref = make_ref(),
        Pid ! { fork, { Ref, self() } },
        get_response( Ref ).

get_state( Pid ) ->
        Ref = make_ref(),
        Pid ! { get_state, { Ref, self() } },
        get_response( Ref ).

change_state( Pid, Data ) ->
        Ref = make_ref(),
        Pid ! { change_state, Data, { Ref, self() } },
        get_response( Ref ).

get_response( Ref ) ->
        receive
                { Ref, Message } -> Message
        end.

responseTo( { Ref, Pid }, Mes ) ->
        Pid ! { Ref, Mes }.

processData( Data, State ) ->
        %%
        %% here comes logic of processing data
        %% and changing process state
        %%
        NewState = Data,
        Response = { { old_state, State }, { new_state, NewState } },
        { Response, NewState }.
```

Lets test it in erlang shell:

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
```

Creating parent process with initial state `first_state`

```
2> ParentPid = spawn( test, loop, [ first_state ] ).
<0.38.0>
3> test:get_state( ParentPid ).
{curr_state,first_state}
4>
```

Lets change state of parent process to `second_state`:

```
4> test:change_state( ParentPid, second_state ).
{{old_state,first_state},{new_state,second_state}}
```

Fork new process from parent process:

```
5> ChildPid = test:fork( ParentPid ).
<0.42.0>
```

Check state of forked process (it is the same as in parent process):

```
6> test:get_state( ChildPid ).
{curr_state,second_state}
```

Comment: Accept this answer since it helps me most. Do you know if there's any approach to *clone* the *control flow* as well as the states (data) ?

Comment: @Xiao Jia, I don't know if this is what you really want: but, as I understand - *flow control is based on current state of process*. So, after forking child process with almost the same state, you may pass it message, in which told him to do something (or do the same things as parent process). So it simulates kind of cloning of flow control.

Comment: conceptually that's ok. But I'm trying to write a third-party utility which can actually do forking while hide details from the user.

Answer (score 4):

(This question was [also answered in the erlang-questions mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-September/069025.html).)

Erlang does not have a 'fork' operation. It has a `spawn` operation however:

```
parent_process() ->
  will_be_executed_by_parent_process(),
  spawn(fun() -> will_be_executed_by_child_process() end),
  will_also_be_executed_by_parent_process().
```

... where function names show in what context they will be executed. Note that any data passed to the child process will be *copied* to the new process' heap.

Comment: I think this is different from Unix `fork`. If you consider the `spawn` as a `fork` (I know they are different, just saying the position in the code), `will_also_be_executed_by_parent_process()`, by the _semantics_ of Unix `fork`, should be executed by the child process as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fork in Erlang. But you can use one among spawn/1, spawn/2, spawn/3, spawn/4 (see also spawn_link) that are BIFs of erlang [see erlang module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html).

So, for example:

```
-module(mymodule).
-export([parent_fun/0]).

parent_fun() ->
    io:format("this is the parent with pid: ~p~n", [self()]),
    spawn(fun() -> child_fun() end),
    io:format("still in parent process: ~p~n", [self()]).

child_fun() ->
    io:format("this is child process with pid: ~p~n", [self()]).
```

Execute in erlang shell as:

```
mymodule:parent_fun().
```

Note that parent process and child process have different pids.

I strongly suggest you to read: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-concurrency

Comment: Same problem as the answer by @aronisstav. `io:format("still in parent process: ~p~n", [self()])` should also be executed by the child process, right? But if you `spawn` in this way, the *control flow* are separated.